# How to add a row that sums a column by group and doesn't count a category in R?

Tags: r, dplyr

I have the following dataframe:

```
data <- data.frame(tag = c("01 - Number_of_academic_staff_FTE", "01 - Number_of_academic_staff_FTE", "01 - Number_of_academic_staff_FTE", "01 - Number_of_academic_staff_FTE", "01 - Number_of_academic_staff_FTE", "01 - Number_of_academic_staff_FTE", "01 - Number_of_academic_staff_FTE", "01 - Number_of_academic_staff_FTE"),
               recorte_niveis = c("_NÃO INFORMADO", "_NÃO INFORMADO", "ARTS & HUMANITIES", "ARTS & HUMANITIES", "ENGINEERING & TECHNOLOGY","ENGINEERING & TECHNOLOGY", "UFRJ", "UFRJ"),
               ano_base = c(2021, 2021, 2021, 2021, 2021, 2021,2021, 2021),
               TURNO = c("INTEGRAL", "PARCIAL", "INTEGRAL", "PARCIAL", "INTEGRAL", "PARCIAL", "INTEGRAL", "PARCIAL"),
               Valor = c(5, 6, 10, 20, 2, 5, 17, 31))
```

In "recorte_niveis" I have a category called "_NÃO INFORMADO" and in the "TURNO" variable I have two categories "PARCIAL" and "INTEGRAL". There's already a sum variable "Valor", I want to add a row that sums "Valor" excluding "_NÃO INFORMADO" and grouping by "TURNO". Like the example below:

```
data <- data.frame(tag = c("01 - Number_of_academic_staff_FTE", "01 - Number_of_academic_staff_FTE", "01 - Number_of_academic_staff_FTE", "01 - Number_of_academic_staff_FTE", "01 - Number_of_academic_staff_FTE", "01 - Number_of_academic_staff_FTE", "01 - Number_of_academic_staff_FTE", "01 - Number_of_academic_staff_FTE", "01 - Number_of_academic_staff_FTE", "01 - Number_of_academic_staff_FTE"),
                   recorte_niveis = c("_NÃO INFORMADO", "_NÃO INFORMADO", "ARTS & HUMANITIES", "ARTS & HUMANITIES", "ENGINEERING & TECHNOLOGY","ENGINEERING & TECHNOLOGY", "UFRJ", "UFRJ", "UFRJ2", "UFRJ2"),
                   TURNO = c("INTEGRAL", "PARCIAL", "INTEGRAL", "PARCIAL", "INTEGRAL", "PARCIAL", "INTEGRAL", "PARCIAL", "INTEGRAL", "PARCIAL"), 
ano_base = c(2021, 2021, 2021, 2021, 2021, 2021,2021, 2021, 2021, 2021),
                       Valor = c(5, 6, 10, 20, 2, 5, 17, 31, 12, 25))
```

It adds two "UFRJ2" rows summing "Valor" grouping by "TURNO" and not couting "_NÃO INFORMADO".

How can I do that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The simplest approach is to filter out the rows you want, group, then `bind_rows`.

```r
library(dplyr)
data %>%
  filter(recorte_niveis != "_NÃO INFORMADO") %>%
  group_by(TURNO) %>%
  summarize(Valor = sum(Valor)) %>%
  bind_rows(data, .)
#                                  tag           recorte_niveis ano_base    TURNO Valor
# 1  01 - Number_of_academic_staff_FTE           _NÃO INFORMADO     2021 INTEGRAL     5
# 2  01 - Number_of_academic_staff_FTE           _NÃO INFORMADO     2021  PARCIAL     6
# 3  01 - Number_of_academic_staff_FTE        ARTS & HUMANITIES     2021 INTEGRAL    10
# 4  01 - Number_of_academic_staff_FTE        ARTS & HUMANITIES     2021  PARCIAL    20
# 5  01 - Number_of_academic_staff_FTE ENGINEERING & TECHNOLOGY     2021 INTEGRAL     2
# 6  01 - Number_of_academic_staff_FTE ENGINEERING & TECHNOLOGY     2021  PARCIAL     5
# 7  01 - Number_of_academic_staff_FTE                     UFRJ     2021 INTEGRAL    17
# 8  01 - Number_of_academic_staff_FTE                     UFRJ     2021  PARCIAL    31
# 9                               <NA>                     <NA>       NA INTEGRAL    29
# 10                              <NA>                     <NA>       NA  PARCIAL    56
```

I'm assuming you will actually have other grouping that includes `tag` and `ano_base` so that they will not be `NA`. If not, you need to determine how you intend to fill them.

---

Despite *"grouping by TURNO"*, if I infer that you are intending this to be by `tag` and `ano_base` as well, then

```r
data %>%
  filter(recorte_niveis != "_NÃO INFORMADO") %>%
  group_by(tag, ano_base, TURNO) %>%
  summarize(recorte_niveis = "UFRJ2", Valor = sum(Valor)) %>%
  bind_rows(data, .)
#                                  tag           recorte_niveis ano_base    TURNO Valor
# 1  01 - Number_of_academic_staff_FTE           _NÃO INFORMADO     2021 INTEGRAL     5
# 2  01 - Number_of_academic_staff_FTE           _NÃO INFORMADO     2021  PARCIAL     6
# 3  01 - Number_of_academic_staff_FTE        ARTS & HUMANITIES     2021 INTEGRAL    10
# 4  01 - Number_of_academic_staff_FTE        ARTS & HUMANITIES     2021  PARCIAL    20
# 5  01 - Number_of_academic_staff_FTE ENGINEERING & TECHNOLOGY     2021 INTEGRAL     2
# 6  01 - Number_of_academic_staff_FTE ENGINEERING & TECHNOLOGY     2021  PARCIAL     5
# 7  01 - Number_of_academic_staff_FTE                     UFRJ     2021 INTEGRAL    17
# 8  01 - Number_of_academic_staff_FTE                     UFRJ     2021  PARCIAL    31
# 9  01 - Number_of_academic_staff_FTE                    UFRJ2     2021 INTEGRAL    29
# 10 01 - Number_of_academic_staff_FTE                    UFRJ2     2021  PARCIAL    56
```

The filling in of `recorte_niveis`, since that is the field we are aggregating, is just assigning whatever value you think relevant (`"UFRJ2"`), nothing magical. The filling in of the other columns to me suggests they should be part of the grouping.

Comment: Based on OP's expected output, it looks like the last two rows (UFRJ2) are just UFRJ, minus the  "_NÃO INFORMADO" values (Integral = 12, Parcial = 25 in the expected output).  Maybe a university total or something like that.  In your current solution, the new rows include the already-totaled UFRJ row values.

Comment: @andrew_reece exactly!

Comment: @LanaMeijinhos, you have not explained how it is that we're supposed to know to carry those forward. Do you want me to sample from the possible values and give you randomness? Would you prefer to always carry-forward the last values of `tag`? Or is it somehow meaningful? Are you intending that the new `Valor` values be specific to each `tag`/`ano_base` grouping as well? I can guess a lot of things, most of them wrong, and I did not see anything clear in your question.

Comment: Specifically, you say "grouping by TURNO", which literally means no other grouping, so ... any other conclusion is either based on random sampling, luck-of-the-draw, last-observation-carried-forward (LOCF), or several other things.

Comment: @LanaMeijinhos, see my next guess. If that doesn't cover it, please edit your question to better explain how we're supposed to impute those values if not by grouping or random sampling.

Comment: @r2evans I'm sorry, I thought it was implied.  I just want to add two rows that sum the column "Valor" by the variable "TURNO", excludingo "NAO INFORMADO", so I have two different totals. One summing everything and the other one summing everything without "NAO INFORMADO". Again, sorry about the way I wrote the post, english is not my first language.

Comment: You explicitly said grouping by TURNO, that doesn't leave room for implication on grouping. I understand about non-native languages, I really do, I would really hate to do this in a different language and I have the utmost respect for those that do. Does my recent edit solve your data problem?

Comment: @r2evans your code was summing "UFRJ" as well since it was filtering only "NAO INFORMADO", obviously I wasn't clear in the post. So filtered both "NAO INFORMADO" and "UFRJ" and your code worked perfectly. Thank you so much for you help!